# How to close a channel inside recursive function

Tags: go

I tried to find a similar question but I couldn't, so here I am asking:

---

I'm using `close(ch)` inside a recursive function. I need to close channel to terminate a `range` loop. However, since the function is recursive, the `close` is run multiple times which gives me:

> panic: close of closed channel

If I comment-out the `close(ch)` statement, I receive:

> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

Please find below my code:

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/tree"
import "fmt"

// Walk walks the tree t sending all values
// from the tree to the channel ch.
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    ch<-(t.Value)
    if t.Left != nil { Walk(t.Left, ch) }
    if t.Right != nil { Walk(t.Right, ch) }
    close(ch) // => How to close a channel inside recursive function? ***
    return
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go Walk(tree.New(1), ch)
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Print(i, " ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Closing a shared channel inside a recursive function is a fundamental design flaw.

Comment: @Adrian That's right. I implemented the solution suggested by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Close the channel outside of the recursive function:

```
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    ch<-(t.Value)
    if t.Left != nil { Walk(t.Left, ch) }
    if t.Right != nil { Walk(t.Right, ch) }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(ch)
        Walk(tree.New(1), ch)
    }()
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Print(i, " ")
    }
}
```

Edit: This answer follows a common Go idiom of using `defer` for cleanup actions. As comments have noted, the `defer` is not necessary. The body of the anonymous function can also be written as:

```
        Walk(tree.New(1), ch)
        close(ch)
```

Comment: Isn't is against the advice that "Only the sender should close a channel, never the receiver." ? (From A Tour of Go, when it talks about Range and Close)

Comment: @MichelePiccolini  The answer follows the advice. The sending goroutine closes the channel, not the receiving goroutine.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I was thinking about Walk being the sender, while we might consider the sender to be the whole lambda that calls Walk and defers close(ch). Stupid question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @MichelePiccolini The advice refers to goroutines, not functions. How the code executed by the goroutines is split into functions is not relevant to the advice.

Comment: Yes you are right. My confusion was just due to the fact that I was coming from trying to solve the esercise with Walk as the only thing spawned with `go`. Therefore in my mind I had "Walk = goroutine".

Comment: @JCarlosR's answer below makes a good point - what's the functional difference between a `defer close(ch)` and a `close(ch)` after `Walk(...)`? I assume there is none, but I'm just starting in go and curious.

Comment: @elBradford There is no functional difference in this example. See edited answer.

Comment: If the `Walk` function used goroutines recursively (perhaps because we want to do some expensive computation the value hence parallelize the Walk), how would we close the channel? For example one of the ifs of modified `Walk` looks like this:     `if t.Left != nil { go Walk(t.Left, ch) }`

Comment: @SumanChapai To process the values in multiple goroutines, run a worker pool to receive the values from `ch`.

Answer (score 3):

[Cerise Limón](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728991/cerise-lim%C3%B3n)'s answer works fine. I just wanted to mention that it's not mandatory to use `defer` inside the closure:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/tour/tree"
)

func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    if t.Left != nil { Walk(t.Left, ch) }
    ch <- t.Value
    if t.Right != nil { Walk(t.Right, ch) }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        Walk(tree.New(1), ch)
        close(ch)
    }()

    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Print(i, " ")
    }
}
```

After the `Walk` function finishes, the channel is closed, and both actions are performed in a separated goroutine.

If we use

```
go Walk(tree.New(1), ch)
close(ch)
```

We are starting a goroutine but closing the channel immediately in the current one.

---

Since I wanted to close the channel inside the recursive function, I ended up doing this:

```
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int, closeAtTheEnd bool) {
    if t.Left != nil {
        // fmt.Println("Walk the Left of", t.Value)
        Walk(t.Left, ch, false)
    } 

    // fmt.Println("Send to the channel:", t.Value)
    ch <- t.Value

    if t.Right != nil {
        // fmt.Println("Walk the Right of", t.Value)
        Walk(t.Right, ch, false)
    } 

    if closeAtTheEnd {
        close(ch)
    }
}
```

That way, recursive calls won't close the channel, and only the first call of `Walk` is allowed to do that (the tree starts at the root node and closes the channel after walking both directions).

```
func useWalkAndPrintTreeValues(k int) {
    c := make(chan int, 10)

    go Walk(tree.New(k), c, true)

    for x := range c {
        fmt.Print(x, " ")   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this way of writing it to be much cleaner

```
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int){
    WalkRecurse(t, ch)
    close(ch)
}
func WalkRecurse(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int){
    if t.Left != nil {
        WalkRecurse(t.Left, ch)
    }
    ch <- t.Value
    if t.Right != nil {
        WalkRecurse(t.Right, ch)
    }
}
func main(){
   ch := make(chan int)
   go Walk(tree.New(1), ch)
   for i := range ch {
      fmt.Println(i)
   }
}
```